# How to change the value of an item in a Flex ArrayCollection

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have an ArrayCollection with values predefined. I want to assign a new value to items in the arrayCollection. This new value is define after datagrid ItemEditEnd.

```
private var tabRV :Array=[
                {thevalue:"25",height:"115",col:"foo"},
                {thevalue:"45",height:"115", col:"foo"},
                {thevalue:"15",height:"115",col:"bb"},
                {thevalue:"95",height:"115", col:"aa"},
                ];

    [Bindable] 
    public var acRDV:ArrayCollection=new ArrayCollection(tabRV);
```

My ItemEditEnd, look like this:

```
private function getCellInfo(event:DataGridEvent):void {


            // Get the new value from the editor.
            var newVal:String = event.currentTarget.itemEditorInstance.htmlText;

            // Get the old value.
            var oldVal:String = 
                event.currentTarget.editedItemRenderer.data[event.dataField]; 
            DP_LISTEREDVCLI[event.rowIndex].thevalue=newVal;
            DP_LISTEREDVCLI[event.rowIndex].col=1;
            trace("xml new val "+DP_LISTEREDVCLI[event.rowIndex].[event.columnIndex]+"/"+DP_LISTEREDVCLI[event.rowIndex].[DP_LISTEREDVCLI.length]);


        }
```

I hope to create a generic function, DP_LISTEREDVCLI[event.rowIndex][event.columnIndex] but it doesn't work. Indeed in this case a new attribute is creating [event.columnIndex value]

Thanks for helping

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not sure what your question is.

Comment: This seems very convoluted to me. Why don't you just edit the data from within the ItemEditor (possibly using data binding)? That's what it's for.

Comment: I edit data with itemrenderer but I need to update dataprovider.